# WPF MVVM - Simple Binding Button with Textbox (Icommand)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, icommand

What I'm trying to do is: when the textbox contains the value "123" it should enable the button and allow me to click it.

[Solution Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spdF7.png) &
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGmI8.png)

I can not find a way to trigger the Button Command (Class called SpecialCommand.cs) based on my Button parameters. Could you support where I'm getting this MVVM pattern wrong?

WPF View [MainWindow.xaml]:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ViewModel:MainWindowVM x:Key="WindowVm"></ViewModel:MainWindowVM>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Margin="0, 5" Text="123"/>
        <Button Content="Click me!" Margin="0, 5" Command="{Binding SpecialCommand, Source={StaticResource WindowVm}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel [MainWindowVM.cs]:

```
public class MainWindowVM
{
    private SpecialCommand _specialCommand;

    public SpecialCommand SpecialCommand { get => _specialCommand; set => _specialCommand = value; }

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        _specialCommand = new SpecialCommand();
    }

}
```

Command [SpecialCommand.cs]

```
public class SpecialCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter != null && (parameter as string) == "123")
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button Pressed!");
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

What I believe, maybe this is what I'm getting wrong is since Button & Textbox are in the View I don't need add/modify any method in my SpecialCommand implementation. They should be able to see when a property is changed.
Like the CanExecuteChanged() below, this command raises a lot of times and seems overkill for this small task.

```
 public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make it more complicated than it needs to be.

```
public class MainWindowVM
{
    private string m_OneTwoThree;
    public string OneTwoThree{
        get { return OneTwoThree; }
        set {
            if (m_OneTwoThree != value){
                m_OneTwoThree = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(OneTwoThree)); //if you need this let me know
            }
        }
    }       

    public MainWindowVM()
    {

    }


    public ICommand RandomCommand { get { return new RelayCommand(OnRandom, IsOneTwoThree); } }


    private void OnRandom()
    {
        //do stuff
    }

    private bool IsOneTwoThree(){
        if (OneTwoThree == "123"){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

You'll also have to update your `xaml` I don't think it'll be able to find 'OneTwoThree' so you'll have to bind it yourself, however you usually would.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Margin="0, 5" Text="{Binding OneTwoThree}"/>
    <Button Content="Click me!" Margin="0, 5" Command="{Binding RandomCommand, Source={StaticResource WindowVm}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

If you have any questions just ask.

This is my RelayCommand : Use RelayCommand("thing to execute", "if function returns true you can execute");

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    private Action methodToExecute;
    private Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator;
    public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute, Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator)
    {
        this.methodToExecute = methodToExecute;
        this.canExecuteEvaluator = canExecuteEvaluator;
    }
    public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute)
        : this(methodToExecute, null)
    {
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.canExecuteEvaluator == null) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            bool result = this.canExecuteEvaluator.Invoke();
            return result;
        }
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.methodToExecute.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your reply. I like your implementation of RelayCommand. Yes it works as expected without any weird behavior like previous answer. The only thing I think is this creates another two extra methods in my code, but if this is the best approach I will be using it from now on.

Comment: The only thing I do not understand is why we have the CanExecute: object parameter. Look like we dont need this parameter and there is no way to actually use it together with the Button CommandParameter = "{}".

Comment: The `CanExecute` checks if `IsOneTwoThree()` returns true or false, if it's true the button will be enabled, if false the button will be disabled.

Comment: You wont need to use `CommandParameter` as the `TextBox` is bound to the field `OneTwoThree` on the `ViewModel` we can just check if `OneTwoThree == "123"`

Comment: Also updated the code with a `NotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to tell the command that it should check whether it `CanExecute`. This is done by triggering the event `CanExecuteChanged`. It tells the button to requery the `CanExecute` property.

For this to work, I would add a text property to your view model and bind the textbox to it.

In `SpecialCommand` add the method:

```
public void TriggerCanExecuteChanged()
{
    CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

In the class `MainWindowVM` add the property:

```
private string _text;
public string Text
{
    get { return _text; }
    set {
        if (value != _text) {
            _text = value;
            _specialCommand.TriggerCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

---

View Model to implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` (see comments):

```
public class MainWindowVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SpecialCommand SpecialCommand { get; set; } = new SpecialCommand();

    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set {
            if (value != _text) {
                _text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Text));
                SpecialCommand.TriggerCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Oliver, thanks for the reply. I've tried your code but I'm having an issue with it. Look like if I raise/trigger the TriggerCanExecuteChanged() method, there is a delay between the value SpecialCommand is receiving and the property itself. What I have here, I need to type "1234" so it raises and my button gets enabled.

Comment: I did another test, look like my Button receive the old parameter before the value is changed in the property. Maybe this picture will explain better what is the issue: https://imgur.com/3eNldov. The new value is 1234, old value _text = "123". So the parameter is a delayed text property result. Very weird?

Comment: Instead of using this parameter, you can pass a reference of your VM to the command and use the `Text` property. Use `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in the textbox. If you don't, the button might only be updated on validation, i.e. after leaving the thextbox. You can also have the VM implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the `Text` property trigger the `PropertyChanged` event when it changes. This necessary if you want changes to the VM be reflected in the textbox immediately.